# 2 wordpress loops showing 1 post from same post type - how to avoid showing the same post?

Tags: wp-query, query, sidebar, exclude, duplicates

I got to two loops in my template files. Both querying the same thing essentially.

This loop in my header:

```
$testimonial_head = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'testimonial',
    'post_status'   => 'published',
    'orderby'   => 'rand'     
));

if ($testimonial_head->have_posts()) :
```

and this loop in my side bar:

```
$testimonial_sidebar = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'testimonial',
    'post_status'   => 'published',
    'orderby'   => 'rand'     
));

if ($testimonial_sidebar->have_posts()) :
```

When these are running that same time, what would be a method of stopping the sidebar query showing the same post as the first header query?

I just never ever want a duplicate to be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your two queries are identical, meaning you only need one of them. The basic solution is:

```
global $testimonials;
$testimonials = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2, /* <-- get both */
    'post_type'     => 'testimonial',
    'post_status'   => 'published',
    'orderby'   => 'rand',
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true /* you need this to control post count accurately */     
));

// header
if ($testimonials->have_posts()) {
  while($testimonials->have_posts()) {
    $testimonials->the_post();
    // whatever you need to do with the post content
    break; // stop the Loop; no complex logic needed since you are printing one and moving on
  }
}

// sidebar
// pretty much the same as the above
global $testimonials;
// this Loop will pick  up where the other left off
if (!empty($testimonials) && $testimonials->have_posts()) {
  while($testimonials->have_posts()) {
    $testimonials->the_post();
    // whatever you need to do with the post content
  }
}
```

There are probably better ways to do this. I'd strongly consider rolling the whole thing into a class and avoiding the global altogether.

```
class Testimonial_Loop {
  static $testimonials = false;

  function get_testimonials() {
    if (empty(static::$testimonials)) {
      static::$testimonials = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 2, /* <-- get both */
        'post_type'     => 'testimonial',
        'post_status'   => 'published',
        'orderby'   => 'rand',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
      ));
    }
    return static::$testimonials;
  }

  function loop() {
    $testimonials = self::get_testimonials();
    if ($testimonials->have_posts()) {
      while($testimonials->have_posts()) {
        $testimonials->the_post();
        the_title();
        // whatever you need to do with the post content
        break; // stop the Loop; no complex logic needed since you are printing on and moving on
      }
    }
  }

}

Testimonial_Loop::loop();
Testimonial_Loop::loop();
```

And a third solution using a function and a static variable:

```
function testimonial_loop() {
  static $testimonials = false;

  if (empty($testimonials)) {
    $testimonials = new WP_Query(array(
      'posts_per_page' => 2, /* <-- get both */
      'post_type'     => 'post',
      'post_status'   => 'published',
      'orderby'   => 'rand',
      'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
    ));
  }

  if ($testimonials->have_posts()) {
    while($testimonials->have_posts()) {
      $testimonials->the_post();
      // whatever you need to do with the post content
      break; // stop the Loop; no complex logic needed since you are printing on and moving on
    }
  }
}
testimonial_loop();
testimonial_loop();
```

Comment: +1 great solution to this. 3 additional notes: the class approach is overkill, it will use more memory and generally be slower. The `while` loops are unnecessary, you just have to run `$testimonials->the_post()` if you're getting one post. Lastly, don't forget to run `wp_reset_postdata()` after you're done with your testimonial code.

Comment: Points worth considering but the class solution runs at worst about 1/10000th slower that the other option, but it stays out of global scope, it represents less code, more maintainable code, more extensible code, and more functional code (the Loop is populated the first time it is used; the sidebar Loop isn't dependent upon the header Loop). The `while`s are unnecessary, but convenient if you wanted to extend the code to print, say, 3 posts per cycle instead of just one, and the execution time without those `while`s is virtually indistinguishable from the execution time with them.

Comment: The class route here is actually about 2x slower (data-supported, but nothing I can link to), and while it keeps `$testimonials` out of the global variable scope, it adds a class to the global class space. Six of one, yadda yadda. The `while` tip was for OP, since he specifically only wants 1. I didn't mean to offend or step on toes; just wanted to add to your answer in a constructive way to help OP.

Comment: @MatthewBoynes : No offense taken. Like I said, points worth considering. I did look into it after your previous comment and I am not getting 2x the execution time for the class. I get about 1.2x for the class relative to the bare loop solution (data-supported but nothing I can link to).

Comment: Instead of using `while` loops, couldn't you just use the `next_post()` method of the `WP_Query` object? e.g. `$testimonials->the_post(); $testimonials->next_post(); $testimonials->the_post();`

Comment: @MarcDingena : I rarely use that method but it looks like it would probably work.

Comment: @s_ha_dum this is great thank you for this answer. Both work nice. Not really fussed about speed but the fisrt option did just what I was after. Thank you. +1

Answer (score 1):

In the header loop, store the post id in e.g. `$header_post_id`

In your sidebar:

```
$testimonial_sidebar = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__not_in' => array($header_post_id), // exclude the post in header
    'post_type'     => 'testimonial',
    'post_status'   => 'published',
    'orderby'   => 'rand'     
));

if ($testimonial_sidebar->have_posts()) :
```

Comment: This also worked. Simple

Answer (score 0):

"**Not a tested answer**":
You can try using a global variable in single template file. This variable will be used to store the `ID` of the post which is displayed in the header loop. While using your sidebar loop use `post__not_in` parameter for your `WP_Query` which will exclude the post displayed in header.

Edit: Refer [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for more information. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12638734/how-do-i-declare-a-global-variable-in-php-i-can-use-across-templates#answer-12638801) for setting the global variable.